# trying to process --options with checkOptions works only if --option=value, and not with --option value

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

Using lazarus 2.0.6 i am trying to build a multi-language application. That works now.
i now need to determine if the language option --lang was mentioned on the command line.

when i start the program with appname --lang=de it passes the check `checkOptions('l:', 'lang:')`

when i start the program with appname --lang de it fails the check `checkOptions('l:', 'lang:')` with error ""Option at position 1 needs an argument :"

the option --lang de DOES bring up the correct language, same as --lang=de

information from here -->
https://wiki.freepascal.org/Step-by-step_instructions_for_creating_multi-language_applications

====

First of all, the LCLTranslator unit gives access to commandline switches --lang or -l to override the automatic language detetion. For example,
imgview.exe --lang de

====

how can i extract the command line option value after --lang using getOptionValue or something similar when the option is given as --lang de?

Comment: Use the ParamStr() and ParamCount functions.

Comment: @ MartynA: yes, i know that. but that would put the burden on me, while i like the system to sort it out for me. that is why there is getOptionValue. the thing i do not understand is both options (--lang=de  and --lang de) work, but only one is correctly processed by getOptionValue. Thanks for reacting anyway.

Comment: Found some or info here: r61041 LCLTranslator: also allow "--lang=<lang>" commandline parameter in addition to "-l <lang>" and "--lang <lang>", bug 35432. it states : r61041 LCLTranslator: also allow "--lang=<lang>" commandline parameter in addition to "-l <lang>" and "--lang <lang>", bug 35432. so now we know WHY it works. left is the question why getOptionValue does not recognise it.